# $\int _{A} x^{2020}\,\mbox {d}(x,y)=\int _0^1\int _{-\frac {\pi }{2}}^{\frac {\pi }{2}}\cos (\varphi )^{2020}r^{2021}\,\mbox {d}\varphi \,\mbox {d}r$

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

$$A = \left\{(x,y) \in \mathbb {R}^2\,|\, x \geq 0 \mbox { and } \sqrt {x^2+y^2} \leq 1\right\}$$

$$\int _{A} x^{2020}\,\mbox {d}(x,y)=\int _0^1\int _{-\frac {\pi }{2}}^{\frac {\pi }{2}}\cos (\varphi )^{2020}r^{2021}\,\mbox {d}\varphi \,\mbox {d}r$$

Is this correct?

Comment: Looking at this now, but as an aside I am curious, is this a math competition problem? Really seems like it with using the year as a number in the problem.

Comment: Yes it is correct, you just converted the original integral into polar coordinates.

Comment: Thanks! No, this is just my Analysis 3 homework